# How would I include a Twitter Timeline into an HTML file?

Tags: html, twitter

How can use the twitter API's to get my timeline and display it in a HTML page? I want to query the API's using HTML.

The questions I found on Stack Overflow are old and the answers don't seem to work any more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share any code from your attempts thus far.

Comment: @APAD1: I'm just going through the documentation. I could not find out where to get the authentication token for using twitter API. I have no clue about it. I don't have a working code yet. I'm just trying to call "GET statuses / home_timeline" API in my js file and not sure what to do. Can you please help?

Comment: Generating authentication tokens is [explained here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/access-tokens.html). Unfortunately you're going to be hard-pressed to find any help here unless you show that you've at least given it a shot yourself. When you get stuck, start a new question regarding the specific hurdle your facing and the code you have for that issue.

Comment: @APAD1: Thanks for the link. Is there some example code on how we can retrieve the tweets using API ? Because, to get the consumber_key/token I need to create an app in developer portal and also it is asking for website address which i dont have. All i need is to get the tweets from my timeline. can you please help here?

Comment: Why not just use the script provided by Twitter? It's quite large, but is officially supported.

Comment: @ jhpratt : which script from Twitter? can you please provide details.

Comment: @user2439903 I've just posted an answer regarding the script I mentioned, as well as a possible remedy for the large size that Twitter hasn't responded to.

Comment: @user2439903 Does my suggestion and subsequent answer help? If not, please let me know and I can make the necessary modifications.

Comment: @jhpratt: thanks for your answer. I'm still trying out and will get back.

Comment: Just a heads up, bounty is about to enter the grace period. Not sure if Stack Overflow gives you a notification.

Answer (score 7):

You can embed your timeline from twitter using this url: https://publish.twitter.com/

Enter your profile url from twitter.

It will generate a code similar to following:

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
  href="https://twitter.com/elonmusk">
    Tweets by elonmusk
</a> 
<script async 
  src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
  charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If you copy and paste the above code into your html, it will embed Elon Musk's twitter timeline.

You can also customize some settings while you're in the website.

#### What this code does:

At the time of writing; It basically inserts 2 `<script>` tags in the `<head>` tag. Also replaces the `<a>` tag with a generated `<iframe>` with twitter's own styling for the timeline. So it doesn't matter what you write in the `<a>` tag. Only the href attribute should be your timeline link and you should also keep the *twitter-timeline* class.

Comment: You're going to be awarded the partial bounty in a bit, but FWIW I believe you should've provided some more info about customization and what the script even does.

Comment: I thought it was self explanatory example to say that: "it will embed Elon Musk's twitter timeline." You can edit the question or tell me here and I can improve the answer. @jhpratt

Comment: That doesn't explain how the script works, though, and what differentiates it from just loading plain HTML ripped from Twitter.

Comment: @jhpratt explained the code. You are welcome to fix it. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: I've already posted my own answer that I believe provides some more detail. For whatever reason yours was more popular though! :)

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use the script provided by Twitter after going through [this tool](https://publish.twitter.com/). It relies on a [quite large script](https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) (95 kB minified) to load in the timeline with updates, which is what differentiates that from using the API to load data in.

The code provided is quite simplistic, as you just need a "link" that is then swapped out by Twitter's code.

```html
<script async src='https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'></script>
<a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/AP?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'></a>
```

You can also set some basic customization, such as width, height, and colors from the widget generator.

(I tried making it a snippet, but it fails on Stack Overflow)

Unfortunately, this appears to be the only officially supported way of loading a timeline, short of implementing it with a backend and live updates via the API.

NB: I *have* personally contacted Twitter *with a follow up* asking about the possibility of them open-sourcing the widget script. Doing so would allow anyone to remove the polyfills for features widely supported, as well as ship modern code that isn't transpiled down to ES3. Combined, these efforts would provide a *huge* savings over the current 95k, but unfortunately I did not receive a response to either email.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy paste the below code to understand how twitter API tool works for showing timelineposts , hashtag data as well as you can see if the user is mentioned in any posts.

```
                <?php include("header.php"); ?>
            <?php
            $user_input=$_GET['user_input'];
            $user_count=$_GET['user_count'];
            $user_until=$_GET['user_until'];
            $mention_count=$_GET['mention_count'];
            $hash_count=$_GET['hash_count'];


            $user_until = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($user_until));



            $user_data=userinfo(
            $user_input,
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret
            );

            $user_tweets=user_tweets(
            $user_input,
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret,
            $user_count);



            $mentiondata_content=mentioneddata($oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret,
            $user_input,
            $user_until,
            $mention_count
            );
            $hashtagdata_content=hashtagdata_content($oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret,
            $user_input,
            $user_until,
            $hash_count);




            $myJSON = json_encode($user_data);
            $myJSON2 = json_encode($user_tweets);
            $myJSON3 = json_encode($mentiondata_content);
            $myJSON4 = json_encode($hashtagdata_content);


            $users = array();
            $users[]=json_decode($myJSON, true);
            $users[]=json_decode($myJSON2, true);
            $users[]=json_decode($myJSON3, true);
            $users[]=json_decode($myJSON4, true);
            $myJSONdata = json_encode($users);
            $wikidata=wikipedia($user_data['name']);
            if ($user_data==NULL) {
            ?>
            <style type="text/css">
            .user_profile_sec , .profile_data_sec
            {display: none;}
            </style>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <section class="user_profile_sec"  >
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            Your search results of <?php echo $user_input;?> are given below.
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="<?php echo $user_data['profile_photo'];?>" style="width: 250px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="w3-padding w3-white user_data_sec01">
            <h4><b><?php echo $user_data['name']." </b>| " . $user_data['screen_name'];?> (<?php echo $user_data['user_id']; ?>)
            <?php
            if ($user_data['verified']==1) {
            echo "<span class='fa fa-check verfication_col'></span>";
            }
            ?>
            </h4>
            Followers =<?php echo $user_data['followers_count'];?> /
            Tweets <?php echo $user_data['statuses_count'];?> /
            friends_count =<?php echo $user_data['friends_count'];?> /
            listed_count =<?php echo $user_data['listed_count'];?> /
            favourites_count =<?php echo $user_data['favourites_count'];?>
            <br>
            <?php   echo $wikidata; ?>
            User Description :  <?php echo $user_data['description'];?>  <br>
            User Location : <?php echo $user_data['location'];?><br>
            User url : <a href="<?php echo $user_data['url'];?>" target="_blank">
            <?php echo $user_data['url'];?></a>  <br>
            Created_at : <?php echo $user_data['created_at'];?> <br>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save_userdata_btn" value="<?php echo base64_encode($myJSONdata);?>"><b> Save Data
            <span class="fa fa-save"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  "><b> Download Data
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><b> Clear Data
            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            </section>


            <section class="profile_data_sec">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"> <button class="btn btn-primary showbtn1 btn-block">Show default analysis</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary showbtn1  btn-block">coming soons</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary showbtn1  btn-block">coming soons</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary showbtn1  btn-block">coming soons</button>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">




            <div class="w3-card w3-white w3-padding">
            <div>
            <div class="w3-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary download_data_btn1"><b> Download Data
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-left">
            Result based on Profile.
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" ">
            <div class="table-responsivep">
            <table class="table" id="user_tweets_table1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tweet</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>Retweet</th>
            <th>Likes </th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Mentioned</th>
            <th>Hashtags</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $n=1;
            foreach ($user_tweets as $data) {
            $retweeted = strpos($data['full_text'], "RT");
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $n;?></td>
            <td class="datetb"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data['created_at'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="tweet_text">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false)
            {
            echo $data['full_text'];
            //$sentidata=sentimental_result($data['full_text']);
            }else{
            $rdata=get_tweets($data['id'],
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret);
            echo "<span class='badge'><i class='fa fa-copy w3-border'></i> </span>" .$rdata['retweeted_status']['full_text'];
            $sentidata=sentimental_result($data['full_text']);
            }
            ?>
            <div class="sentidiv">
            <br>
            <?php //echo sentimental_html($sentidata); ?>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $url="https://twitter.com/".$user_for_likes."/status/".$user_id_for_likes."/";
            ?>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn_view" value="<?php echo $url;?>">
            View
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </button>

            </td>
            <td class="nolik retweet_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['retweets'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="nodot likes_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['likes'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="comments_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['comments'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            if ($retweeted === false) {
            echo $data['user']['screen_name'];
            }else{
            echo $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php
            foreach ($data['entities']['user_mentions'] as $key ) {
            echo "@".$key['screen_name']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php
            foreach ($data['entities']['hashtags'] as $key ) {
            echo "#".$key['text']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $n++;
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            </section>
            <!--   ======================================================================  -->

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="w3-card w3-white w3-padding">
            <div>
            <div class="w3-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary download_data_btn2"><b> Download Data
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-left">
            Result based on Mentioning.
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" ">
            <div class="table-responsivep">
            <table class="table " id="user_tweets_table2">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tweet</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>No.Retweet</th>
            <th>No.Likes</th>
            <th>No.Comments</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Mentioned</th>
            <th>Hashtags</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="w3-center">
            <?php
            //print_r($mentiondata_content['statuses']);
            $n=1;
            foreach ($mentiondata_content['statuses'] as $data) {
            $retweeted_hash=strpos($data['text'], "RT");
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td># <?php echo $n; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="datetb">

            <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data['created_at'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="tweet_text">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false)
            {
            $rdatas=get_tweets($data['id'],
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret);
            echo  $rdatas['full_text'];
            }else{
            $rdatad=get_tweets($data['id'],
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret);
            echo "<span class='badge'><i class='fa fa-copy w3-border'></i> </span>" .$rdatad['retweeted_status']['full_text']."</i></span>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $url="https://twitter.com/".$user_for_likes."/status/".$user_id_for_likes."/";
            ?>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn_view" value="<?php echo $url;?>">
            View
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </button>

            </td>
            <td class="nolik retweet_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_retweets($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['retweets'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="nodot likes_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_likes($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['likes'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="comments_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_comments($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['comments'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $data['user']['screen_name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php

            foreach ($data['entities']['user_mentions'] as $key ) {
            echo "@".$key['screen_name']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php
            foreach ($data['entities']['hashtags'] as $key ) {
            echo "#".$key['text']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $n++;
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>







            <br>
            <!--   ======================================================================  -->

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="w3-card w3-white w3-padding">

            <div>
            <div class="w3-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary download_data_btn3"><b> Download Data
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-download"></span> </b>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-left">
            Result based on Hashtag.
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" ">
            <div class="table-responsivep">
            <table class="table " id="user_tweets_table3">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tweet</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>No.Retweet</th>
            <th>No.Likes</th>
            <th>No.Comments</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Mentioned</th>
            <th>Hashtags</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="w3-center">
            <?php
            //print_r($mentiondata_content['statuses']);
            $n=1;
            foreach ($hashtagdata_content['statuses'] as $data) {
            $retweeted_hash=strpos($data['text'], "RT");
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td># <?php echo $n; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="datetb">

            <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data['created_at'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="tweet_text">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false)
            {
            $rdatas=get_tweets($data['id'],
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret);
            echo  $rdatas['full_text'];
            }else{
            $rdatad=get_tweets($data['id'],
            $oauth_access_token,
            $oauth_access_token_secret,
            $consumer_key,
            $consumer_secret);
            echo "<span class='badge'><i class='fa fa-copy w3-border'></i> </span>" .$rdatad['retweeted_status']['full_text']."</i></span>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            $url="https://twitter.com/".$user_for_likes."/status/".$user_id_for_likes."/";
            ?>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn_view" value="<?php echo $url;?>">
            View
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </button>
            </td>
            <td class="nolik retweet_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_retweets($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['retweets'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="nodot likes_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_likes($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['likes'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="comments_tab">
            <?php
            if ($retweeted_hash === false) {
            $user_for_likes= $data['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['id'];
            }else{
            $user_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'];
            $user_id_for_likes= $data['retweeted_status']['id'];
            }
            //echo get_comments($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            $status_array=get_status($user_id_for_likes,$user_for_likes);
            echo $status_array['comments'];
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $data['user']['screen_name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php

            foreach ($data['entities']['user_mentions'] as $key ) {
            echo "@".$key['screen_name']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td class="alignleft">
            <?php
            foreach ($data['entities']['hashtags'] as $key ) {
            echo "#".$key['text']."<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $n++;
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ###########################################################################  -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.btn_view').click(function(){
            var url=$(this).val();
            var urlis="https://twitframe.com/show?url="+url;
            $('.statuses_body_frame').prop('src', urlis);
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
            });


            $('.save_userdata_btn').click(function(){
            var userdata=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save_user_data.php',
            data: { userdata: userdata },
            success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            }
            });

            });


            function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
            var downloadLink;
            var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

            // Specify file name
            filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

            // Create download link element
            downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
            }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

            // Setting the file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            //triggering the function
            downloadLink.click();
            }
            }

            $('.download_data_btn1').click(function(){
            exportTableToExcel("user_tweets_table1","user_datas");
            });
            $('.download_data_btn2').click(function(){
            exportTableToExcel("user_tweets_table2","mentioned_datas");
            });
            $('.download_data_btn3').click(function(){
            exportTableToExcel("user_tweets_table3","hashtag_datas");
            });

            </script>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="statuses_body">
            <iframe class="statuses_body_frame" border=0 frameborder=0  style="height: 70vh;width: 100%;"
            src=""></iframe>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>



            </body>
            </html>

            <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: i can't post the functions.php code. if you wish to get it , i shall post it